# Slider type progress-bar in Xamarin or Windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin form application. I want to create a custom progress bar. A slider which increments it's according to the progress. Initially the slider value should be minimum and should increment it's value according to the progress. When the task is finished the slider should have maximum value. How can I achieve this? is there any windows phone custom progress bar like this? please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```net
var progressBar = new ProgressBar();
```

You can change progress manually:

```net
progressBar.Progress = 0.2f;
```

Or bind it to your ViewModel:

```net
progressBar.SetBinding<YourViewModel>(ProgressBar.ProgressProperty, v => v.YourProgressProperty);
// Then:
YourViewModel.YourProgressProperty = 0.4f;
```

Or you could do some animations:

```net
await progressBar.ProgressTo(0.95f, 250, Easing.Linear);
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar/